# Syntax error when trying to include header files

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, include

I want to include header files in my library project in OpenSSL's way. But I can't make it work.

Suppose my library project looks like this:

```
C:\MYLIB
├─ A
│  ├─A.h
│  └─A.c
├─ B
│  ├─B.h
│  └─B.c
├─ C
│  ├─C.h
│  └─C.c
└─ include
   └─mylib
       ├─A.h
       ├─B.h
       └─C.h
```

Now I have a new project which includes the header files in mylib. I have added C:\MYLIB\include to the additional include directories. The include statement in my new project are:

```
#include <mylib\a.h>
#include <mylib\b.h>
```

where **mylib\a.h** contains only one line to direct to the real A\A.h:

```
../../A/A.h
```

and **mylib\b.h** contains:

```
../../B.B.h
```

Just like the OpenSSL's way. However, my VS2010 is complaining "*error C2059: syntax error:'.'*, while the error leads to first '.' in **mylib\a.h**.

Does these include make sense? How should I include those header files from mylib correctly?

Comment: I believe you need the leading dot to avoid the error you are experiencing. Try `.\..\..\A\A.h`. Also, OpenSSL flattens itself out to `include\mylib` on install. It does not use it during build. During build, the various paths are included with `-I` options.

Comment: I fixed the title of your question to match the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the leading dot, and it still doesn't work. I found this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123667/how-to-include-oppenssl-headers, it says "I'm guessing you're attempting to build on Windows, because the tarfile on a Linux or Unix machine should have fixed up all those symlinks." Would that be the problem? Than I'm building it on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
#include <mylib\a.h>
#include <mylib\b.h>
```

looks wrong (or to be precise: it hurts my eyes .. ;-)

You might like to use a slash:

```
#include <mylib/a.h>
#include <mylib/b.h>
```

Comment: Sorry for your eyes ^^" I replace it with slash as you suggested and it still doesn't work...

Comment: @ChiaraHsieh: What doesn't work? You get the same error as before when you used back-slashes?