# Linking OpenSSL into a dynamic library

Tags: c++, gcc, openssl

I'm trying to static link OpenSSL into my program.

It works fine when linking into the executable. I need to use OpenSSL in a shared library (so, or dll) that I dynamically load later on when the process executes.

Trying to statically link OpenSSL into the shared library causes errors due to OpenSSL not being compiled with -fPIC. Is it possible to do this without recompiling openssl?

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you need to static link it, you may need to compile it yourself.

Comment: You need to compile again to get .so files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to static link OpenSSL into my program.

In this case, its as simple as:

```
gcc prog.c /usr/local/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a -o prog.exe -ldl
```

---

> It works fine when linking into the executable.

Devil's advocate... Does it work fine with Position Independent Code (PIE)? PIE on a program is the equivalent to PIC on a shared object (some hand waiving).

```
gcc -fPIE prog.c /usr/local/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a -o prog.exe -ldl
```

According to the GCC folks, you can compile with `fPIC`, and then build a shared object with `-fPIC` or a relocatable executable with `-fPIE`. That is, its OK to use `-fPIC` for both.

---

> Trying to statically link OpenSSL into the shared library causes errors due to OpenSSL not being compiled with -fPIC.

That's easy enough to fix. You simply specify `shared` in configure:

```
./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make
sudo make install
```

I *think* you can also (notice the lack of `shared`):

```
export CFLAGS="-fPIC"
./config no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make
sudo make install
```

---

> not being compiled with -fPIC. Is it possible to do this without recompiling openssl?

NO, you have to compile with PIC to ensure GCC generates relocatable code.

---

> Also, is there a better way to do this?

Usually you just configure with `shared`. That triggers `-fPIC`, which gets you relocatable code.

There's other things you can do, but they are more intrusive. For example, you can modify `Configure` line (like `linux-x86_64`), and add `-fPIC` in the second field. The fields are separated by colons, and the second field is `$cflags` used by the OpenSSL build system.

You can see an example of modifying `Configure` at [Build OpenSSL with RPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29858870)