# OpenSSL headers missing when building OpenSSH

Tags: openssl, openssh

I want to build a certain OpenSSH version with a specific OpenSSL version from sources, but I get the following error:

```
mkdir /tmp/ssh
cp openssh-6.7p1.tar.gz /tmp/ssh
cp openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz /tmp/ssh
cd /tmp/ssh
tar zxvf openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1l
./config --prefix=/tmp/ssh
make
make install
cd ..
tar zxvf openssh-6.7p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-6.7p1
./configure --with-ssl-dir=/tmp/ssh --prefix=/tmp/ssh

...
checking openssl/opensslv.h usability... no
checking openssl/opensslv.h presence... no
checking for openssl/opensslv.h... no
configure: error: *** OpenSSL headers missing - please install first or check config.log ***
```

Is there a bug in openSSH's configure script or do I have to change any command?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a way without sending flags to `./configure` You need to install OpenSSL first. Get the latest tarball [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/).

```
./config
make
make test
make install
```

Then [install libssl-dev](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=18004)

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Then you can retry [installing OpenSSH:](http://creativenotice.com/2015/08/manual-update-openssh-on-ubuntu/)

```
cd openssh-[version]
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 3):

ftp://ftp.ca.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL says:

> LibreSSL/OpenSSL should be compiled as a position-independent library
>   (i.e. with -fPIC) otherwise OpenSSH will not be able to link with it.
>   If you must use a non-position-independent libcrypto, then you may need
>   to configure OpenSSH --without-pie.

The following commands do not result in the "OpenSSL headers missing" error anymore:

```
tar zxvf openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1l
./config --prefix=/tmp/ssh
make
make install
cd ..
tar zxvf openssh-6.7p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-6.7p1
./configure --with-ssl-dir=/tmp/ssh --prefix=/tmp/ssh --without-pie
```

Comment: Alternatively it is possible to use "./config --prefix=/tmp/ssh shared" and "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/ssh/lib ./configure --prefix=/tmp/ssh --with-ssl-dir=/tmp/ssh".

Comment: I do as your code and the `./configure` is successfull, no matter with `--without-pie` or not. But during the `make` it came out that:

Comment: ```cipher.h:69:17: error: field ‘evp’ has incomplete type
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX evp;
                 ^
Makefile:152: recipe for target 'ssh_api.o' failed```

Comment: I just can't locate the problem. Could you help me with this? My purpose is to install openssh-server witrh a non-sudo prvilege user, my GPU Server is something like that, and I want to enable SSH and SFTP so that I can use the server as a SSH-remote-interpreter in Jetbrains Pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution to this OpenSSL headers missing error.

```
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
cd openssl
./Configure
make
make install
```

Now OpenSSL will be installed and you will no longer get OpenSSL headers missing message.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a bug in openSSH's configure script or do I have to change any command?

According to [Installing OpenSSL and OpenSSH](http://randombio.com/linuxsetup54.html):

> If 'configure' can't find ssl, change the configure command to:
>
> ```
> ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl --with-tcp-wrappers
> ```

The above means the OpenSSL headers are located at `/usr/local/ssl/include` and the libraries are located at `/usr/local/ssl/lib`. I think you need to change the path to `/tmp/ssh`.

---

From:

```
cd openssl-1.0.1l
./config --prefix=/tmp/ssh
...
```

I think you should use:

```
cd openssl-1.0.1l
./config --openssldir=/tmp/ssh/openssl
...
```

Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. You might want to use other options, like `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128`.

---

With OpenSSL in `/tmp/ssh/openssl`, then:

```
cd openssh-6.7p1
./configure --with-ssl-dir=/tmp/ssh/openssl --prefix=/tmp/ssh
...
```

---

Using the non-system provided OpenSSL can cause trouble. So you might also want to check out [Build OpenSSL with RPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29858870/608639). You might also want to build OpenSSH with RPATHs too.

Comment: Changing "./config --prefix=/tmp/ssh" to "./config --openssldir=/tmp/ssh/openssl" and changing "./configure --with-ssl-dir=/tmp/ssh --prefix=/tmp/ssh" to "./configure --with-ssl-dir=/tmp/ssh/openssl --prefix=/tmp/ssh" results in the same "OpenSSL headers missing" error.