# Crypt::OpenSSL::Random won't install because of 'undefined symbol: RAND_egd'

Tags: perl, openssl

I am having trouble installing the [Crypt::OpenSSL::Random](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::OpenSSL::Random) on a Linux machine. I am first getting these warnings:

> ```
> Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lssl
>
> Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lcrypto
> ```

I'm not sure if these are as harmless as they say, because it then fails with:

> ```
> Can't load 'blib/arch/auto/Crypt/OpenSSL/Random/Random.so' for module
> Crypt::OpenSSL::Random: blib/arch/auto/Crypt/OpenSSL/Random/Random.so:
> undefined symbol: RAND_egd at
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 230.  at
> test.pl line 11 Compilation failed in require at test.pl line 11.
> ```

OpenSSL 1.0.1 is properly installed on the machine.

Comment: Depending on which crippled Linux distribution you are using, you may have to install a `-dev`package for OpenSSL. Also, where are the OpenSSL headers and libraries installed? Maybe your `perl` is not configured to look there.

Comment: It sounds like you are using OpenSSL 1.1.0 and [Issue 547: Disable EGD support by default](http://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/547). It sounds like it could be a Perl issue; the Perl binaries needs to be aware of `OPENSSL_NO_EGD`. I guess you need to back peddle and work the two problems: ***`No library found for -lssl`*** and ***`No library found for -lcrypto`***. Did you [build OpenSSL and Perl with an RPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29858870)?

Comment: How did you install the Perl module? This module is available from the package manager (for Debian and CentOS anyway) and it worked for me by just installing the module (on a new image). The package manager route may not be an option but hopefully that helps.

Comment: After I commented I noticed it looks like you are trying to load the module from the source distribution. You'll probably have to also include the path to 'blib/arch/auto' for perl, and install the `-dev` package as noted above (that is all that was required for me to build the package on Debian). Without knowing the OS though, I'm not sure if we can reproduce the messages you report.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to modify the perl and openssl installations. I am working within a very big legacy system with limited access and specific module installations procedures. I tried installing the module by using the make utility.